# How to get to Sultanahmet from Istanbul New Airport?

Tags: airports, buses, transportation, istanbul

Can someone give me instructions on how to get to Sultanahmet from the new airport. I found out about the bus route IST-20 but I couldn't find if it really exists or how much is it and should we buy the tickets before or they sell them at the airport?

Has someone used it before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this travel guide](https://www.travelwithpedro.com/how-to-go-from-istanbul-ataturk-airport-to-sultanahmet/):

> Another option is taking the shuttle bus from Istanbul Airport to Sultanahmet or Taksim. From the arrivals hall, go down to level -2 and the new Havaist buses will be outside. There are buses to every corner of the city.
>
> Buses from Istanbul Airport to Sultanahmet depart from bay 16 and to Taksim from bay 14. The fare is 18 Turkish lira and you can pay directly to the driver (he will come to your seat before departure).
>
> In Sultanahmet, the bus stops at Sultanahmet Square, near Hagia  Sophia. In Taksim, they stop 10-minutes’ walk from Taksim Square.

Comment: The driver does not come to your seat. You pay just before you get into the bus either by credit card or by "Istanbul kart" (city transportation card that you can buy from the machines just over there).